# Implementing an integral test for series convergence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I have to do a project about series convergence. I have to write a package with some tests for convergence. I am having trouble implementing the integral test.

My code is:

```
IntegCon[f_, m_, n_] := 
  Module[{l},
    l = Integrate[f, {n, m, Infinity}];
    If[l < Infinity, "True", "False"]]
```

When I try

```
IntegCon[1/n, 1, n]
```

I get the message

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of 1/n does not converge on {1, ∞}.

Do you have any idea on how can I fix this?

Comment: `Check[l = Integrate[..]; "True", "False", Integrate::idiv]`?

Comment: Do you need to check the other hypotheses of the integral test?

Answer (score 1):

Also has it's flaws, but could integrate to a symbolic upper bound and take a limit. No compelling need to give a lower bound, it can also be some unspecified symbolic constant so long as it is assumed to be fixed and smaller than the upper bound.

I should add that the comment by @MichaelE2 still holds. There are other hypotheses required and the code below makes no pretense of checking them.

```
IntegCon[f_, n_] := Module[{integral, lim},
  integral = 
   Integrate[f, {n, m1, m2}, Assumptions -> 1000 < m1 < m2];
  lim = Limit[integral, m2 -> Infinity];
  FreeQ[lim, DirectedInfinity]]
```

Here are some examples.

```
IntegCon[1/n, n]

(* Out[142]= False *)

IntegCon[1/n^2, n]

(* Out[143]= True *)

IntegCon[1/(n*Log[n]), n] (* slow *)

(* Out[144]= False *)
```